# Append UTF-8 string as ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm developing an urdu website. My problem is that I want to make the query data as ID. I'm using the jQuery `append` function.

When I alert the 'key' that is the dynamic data from database, its result is true, but when I set this as ID of an anchor tag it looks like this:

`id="حکومت" فوج="" کے="" ہاتھ="" میں=""`.

My code is:

```
$.get('urduind.php', {'user' : $(e.target).text()}, function (data) {
    data = data.trim();
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    var item = [];
    $.each(data, function (key, val) {              
        alert(key);             
        $('#leftPanel').append('<a id ='+ key +' class=tags href=#> '+ key +'('+val+')</a>');
    });                 
});
```

I want this to become `id="حکومت فوج کے ہاتھ میں"` using `append`. Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Is your code really on a single line like that?

Comment: Problem in javascript, not in php?

Comment: **Please take the time to format your question properly.** I suggest you read **[Ask]**. I've edited the question this time. (I removed some commented code that's probably irrelevant; feel free to add it back if you think it should be in the question.)

Comment: i edit this.and i want to set id as mention above.in alert key value is accurate but while setting id of ancher tag it broken

Comment: When someone takes time to format you question you should make sure you keep it readable when you make changes. Why should take someone take the time to answer the question if you don't take time to keep a proper and readable formation of the question.

Comment: i m new in writting .i was not understaing .it is done by mistake.and m sorry for that

Comment: Thats why _Amal Murali_ already helped you. I formatted your code once again, so take the time and look how highlighting and formatting works.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, in HTML, attributes must be delimited using quotes when they contain spaces (or, in XHTML, always). My suggestion is doing that always.

In your case, `حکومت فوج کے ہاتھ میں` contains spaces, so you must use `id="'+ key +'"` instead of just `id='+ key +'`:

```
$('#leftPanel').append(
    '<a id="'+key+'" class="tags" href="#">'+ key + '</a>'
);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kLJvx/)

Comment: now m am again have a problem using the same code in yii.when i use above code of line in yii the following parse error occurs.                  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''+key+'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in F:\xampp\htdocs\finalurdu\protected\views\cartoon\test.php on line 20

Comment: @Iqra I don't know yii, it seems it's something server-side, not directly related to javascript. Better ask it in a new question

Comment: Now I have the same problem for href attribute.I used the mention solution but this is not working for href                                   '$('#wordcloud').append('<span data-weight='+val+'>'+'<a  href=?r=tags/view&id="'+key+'"> '+ key +'</a></span>');'

Comment: @StudentofQAu Use `$('#wordcloud').append('<span data-weight="'+val+'"><a href="?r=tags/view&id='+key+'">'+key+'</a></span>');`